# Arquillian with Wildfly 8.0.0.Final Managed not working

Tags: jboss-arquillian, wildfly

I have been using arquillian with jboss-as-7.1.1.Final for a while now.

I want to start using wildfly 8.0.0.Final but I cannot get it to work.

I have changed only my pom.xml and arquillian.xml.

This is my "properties":

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.joda.time>2.1</version.joda.time>
    <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
    <version.mockito>1.9.5</version.mockito>
    <version.jacoco>0.6.0.201210061924</version.jacoco>
    <version.arquillian.bom>1.1.3.Final</version.arquillian.bom>
    <version.arquillian.drone.bom>1.3.0.Final</version.arquillian.drone.bom>
    <version.arquillian.jacoco>1.0.0.Alpha6</version.arquillian.jacoco>
    <version.arquillian.persistence>1.0.0.Alpha6</version.arquillian.persistence>
    <version.commons.collections>3.2.1</version.commons.collections>
    <version.commons.io>2.4</version.commons.io>
    <version.wildfly>8.0.0.Final</version.wildfly>
    <!-- <version.jbpm.3>3.3.1.GA</version.jbpm.3> -->
</properties>
```

The related maven profile declaration looks like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-wildfly-managed</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack</id>
                            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                        <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
                                        <type>zip</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <arquillian.launch>wildfly-as-managed</arquillian.launch>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Ignore/Execute plugin execution -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                <pluginExecutions>
                                    <!-- copy-dependency plugin -->
                                    <pluginExecution>
                                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <action>
                                            <execute />
                                        </action>
                                    </pluginExecution>
                                </pluginExecutions>
                            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
                <type>zip</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.17.GA</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

This is the arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian
xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

<container
    qualifier="wildfly-as-managed"
    default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">target/wildfly-8.0.0.Final</property>
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=9 -Djboss.management.native.port=9080 -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</property>
        <property name="managementPort">9090</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
<extension qualifier="persistence-dbunit">
    <property name="defaultDataSetFormat">YAML</property>
</extension>
</arquillian>
```

and this is the complete error stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerCreationException: Could not create Container wildfly-as-managed
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:56)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeployableContainer must be specified
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:44)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:71)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:76)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any arquillian container dependency in your profile and the stack trace looks like arquillian can't find the container to be used. Did you just forget to add the container to your dependencies?

Try this one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i followed the both instructions, did not work for me

Answer (score -1):

As it is mentioned in the support url
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Container+adapters
arquilliian managed is not supported for wildfly. instead only embedded is supported.

Comment: your reponse is old dated in 2014 manager existing : <dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency> and oher version in alpha version 1.0.0.Alpha4 i use it and it works like a charm